# Grails new Domain(params) initialize results in null field

Tags: grails

I did a Google search but came up dry on anything that explained what is happening...

I have the following domain class:

```
class Company {
  Integer companyId
  String name

  static constraints = {
    companyId unique: true
    name blank: false
  }

  String toString(){
    return name
  }
}
```

When I do a 'new Company(params)' in the controller with the passed in values, it returns an object with the 'companyId' field set to null. I've double checked the values in 'params' and both 'params.name' and 'params.companyId' are set to non-null values.

What am I doing wrong?

I have another domain/controller (created by someone else now gone) doing something similar that works fine so I must be missing *something*.

I'm new to Grails/Groovy and any/all advice welcome.

Comment: Is the `companyId` unique?

Comment: Add `println params` at the beginning of the controller method - what does the output look like?

Comment: 1.double check for spelling/case errors.  Is companyId the only variable not being correctly set? Another troubleshooting idea , set the variables manually   domain.companyId = params.companyId

Comment: It is weird - I put a "def myParams = params" in the controller but left the line "def company = new Company(params)" alone.Now the company object has the companyId field filled in.